# How do I use a pickled model to deploy my Machine Learning model using AWS-Sagemaker after preprocessing the input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have a pickled model (say an XGBoost Model - xgboost_model.sav).
I want to be able to get a json input (through an API invocation), perform some pre-processing (like missing value imputation, outlier treatment etc.), use the pickled file to return the predicted the outcome of the model(say a float denoting probability).
I want to create a sagemaker endpoint which can then be used to get the prediction(a probability) through a lambda function. (using boto3)

I have gone through the example notebooks provided my AWS Sagemaker but am not able to figure out how to execute the above steps and deploy my model.

Please help me with a step by step instruction possibly with some basic code.

Comment: Have you tried this example notebook: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/xgboost_bring_your_own_model/xgboost_bring_your_own_model.ipynb ?

Comment: Yes, I went through that notebook. But there they have trained a XGBoost model on sagemaker itself, saved the model artifacts and loaded it again inside sagemaker. I want to know how do I use a model (random forest) trained outside sagemaker

Comment: You can package your model in Docker container and push to ECR repository. After that you can create model package from that ECR image and then a model from that model package. Here is example how to package code to Docker for this purpose: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container. Training part is not mandatory, you can delete it and leave only prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on BYOC for SageMaker - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms.html

You can package your pre-processing code in your BYOC image or use the inference pipeline feature - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-pipelines.html